# Manually calling a React.PropTypes validation React native "^0.30.0"

Tags: react-native

I have upgraded to the latest version of React/RN:
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-native": "^0.30.0",

And I am starting to get a lot of warnings regarding the stylesheets. I am actually not using React.PropTypes validation for the style sheets, so why is throwing these warnings?

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: "center",
        margin: 10,
    },
```

> ExceptionsManager.js:76 Warning: You are manually calling a
>   React.PropTypes validation function for the `fontSize` prop on
>   `StyleSheet welcome`. This is deprecated and will not work in the next
>   major version. You may be seeing this warning due to a third-party
>   PropTypes library. See https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html
>   for details.reactConsoleError @
>
> ExceptionsManager.js:76 Warning: You are manually calling a
>   React.PropTypes validation function for the `textAlign` prop on
>   `StyleSheet welcome`. This is deprecated and will not work in the next
>   major version. You may be seeing this warning due to a third-party
>   PropTypes library. See https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html
>
> ExceptionsManager.js:76 Warning: You are manually calling a
>   React.PropTypes validation function for the `margin` prop on
>   `StyleSheet welcome`. This is deprecated and will not work in the next
>   major version. You may be seeing this warning due to a third-party
>   PropTypes library. See https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html
>   for details.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

React native 0.30 was dependent on react 15.2.0 not 15.2.1. So you should do `rm -rf node_modules/react`, remove the react version from *package.json*, then `npm install --save react@15.2.0`. This should do the trick.

Comment: Great. Although i was not using React native 0.30 , it resolved the issue.

Comment: react@15.2.1 is OK for the react-native@0.31.0

Comment: React 15.3.0 introduced a new warning but React Native has not been updated yet to fix its usage of React. So you can stick with 15.2.1 until this is fixed in React Native.

Answer (score 7):

I resolved the issue by changing versions (removing from node_modules and installing packages).

```
npm --save remove react react-native
npm --save install react@15.2.1 react-native@0.31.0
```

I didn't re-deploy native code. I was seeing the issues previously when using:

```
"react": "^15.3.0",
"react-native": "^0.31.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this was just a bug with the react version. If you update to version 15.3.0, all the warnings will disappear. Reference:https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4854

Comment: The reference link you provided does not support your answer. The link says: React 15.3.0 the maintainers appear to have deprecated use of PropTypes validation functions. My question is stating I am actually not using React.PropTypes validation for the style sheets so why is throwing the warnings ?

Comment: I have also attempted to upgrade to 15.3.0

Comment: updating to version 15.2.0 will not remove your warnings but updating to 15.3.0 will remove the warning you're referring to in your question.

Comment: Incorrect. Changing to 15.2.0 has removed from warnings.

Comment: Touché, i'll make sure to make amends to my answer. Although your issue would also be fixed updating to version 15.3.0, as my answer does suggest.    This seemed to have done the trick for me.

Comment: I already attempted to update it to 15.3.O the issue still persisted. What version of react native are you using ?