# Button wouldn't respond until I press it several times in React Native

Tags: android, debugging, react-native

I am experiencing a weird bug in my React Native Android project.

There is a media controller page where the custom audio player is implemented (with **Play/Pause**, **Next**, **Previous** buttons etc), and it works just fine on **Android simulators**, but when I try to click on any buttons of it on the **real device**, it just does not respond until I press it like 10 times.

Several causes I can think of:

- The whole page responds to a pan gesture, so on the simulator, a click event is recognized as a click, but on the device, it recognizes it as a pan gesture.
- <del>I get around 1,000 warnings of `Warning: You are manually calling a React.PropTypes validation function...` (of which solution might be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38715799/3930247)), and it could play with the performance of the app.</del>   (This issue is fixed, but it still happens)
- There are a couple of libraries used in the app that are **only implemented for iOS** such as [react-native-streamingkit](https://github.com/LeBlaaanc/react-native-streamingkit) and [react-native-mpremotecommandcenter](https://github.com/LeBlaaanc/react-native-mpremotecommandcenter), and one of them might be causing the issue.

Am I getting around it right? Could any other reason be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the bug - the reason was #1 among the ones I listed out.

The `onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture()` function in one of my `PanResponder`s contained this code:

```
onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => {
    return dx != 0 && dy != 0 && this._canPan;
}
```

In other words, the code was setting the threshold of distinguishing between a tap gesture and pan gesture to **zero**!

I changed it as follows and it is now working beautifully:

```
onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => {
    return (Math.abs(gestureState.dx) > 5 || Math.abs(gestureState.dy) > 5) && this._canPan;
}
```

Set the threshold to 10px if you would like.