# React-Bootstrap: manually calling a React.PropTypes validation function

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

After upgrading my project after coming back to it after 2 weeks I receive lots of warning I can't get rid of:

> warning.js:44 Warning: You are manually calling a React.PropTypes validation function for the `onClick` prop on `NavbarToggle`. This is deprecated and will not work in the next major version. You may be seeing this warning due to a third-party PropTypes library.
>
> warning.js:44 Warning: You are manually calling a React.PropTypes validation function for the `onClick` prop on `NavItem`. This is deprecated and will not work in the next major version. You may be seeing this warning due to a third-party PropTypes library.

Obviously, they have something to do with **react-bootstrap**.

I have found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690502/manually-calling-a-react-proptypes-validation-react-native-0-30-0) for **react-native** where the answers suggest to upgrade dependent libraries versions. I have done so but it didn't no help... I also removed **node_modules** completely and then reinstalled again.

I have looked into [the issues on github](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20) but there ain't a similar one.

How can I correct my app and dismiss the warnings?

**Versions I have:**

- react@15.3.0
- react-bootstrap@0.30.2

Comment: What is the version of `react-bootstrap` you are using? It is hard to help when you don’t give any details. :-(

Comment: My bad! Give me a sec. ;) ... finished, check it out, Dan.

Comment: Can I ask you to provide a minimal project reproducing this? Or a fiddle.

Comment: I hoped it wouldn't go that far... I will wait. Maybe somebody will know right away. If not then I will make the fiddle. Thanks Dan!

Comment: create-react-app myproject && cd myproject && npm i --save react-bootstrap

Comment: Never mind :-) I created a fiddle, can you reproduce it there? https://jsfiddle.net/8ffunb0m/

Comment: In progress again. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121222/discussion-between-zatziky-and-dan-abramov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/53069/) for you:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div><NavItem /></div>;
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

In general, it’s best that you try to do this as part of the question ;-)

I can’t reproduce the warning in that fiddle. If you copy and paste the code using React Bootstrap that triggers this warning, I’ll be happy to take another look.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce it but I have found what's maybe causing my issue. I am not sure thogh. I have updated the question.

Comment: I have found it! I will post the answer soon. Thanks Dan a lot. I thought it was a general issue but it was me however.

Comment: Dan, it was solved by the versions not my change in the answer. Sorry for confisung you.

Answer (score -1):

I solved these errors by uninstalling this version of react which is `react 15.3.0` to `react 15.2.0`.

This is because the latest version of react has removed `PropTypes` from production, so manually adding the PropType will throw an error.

To get more info about this, check out https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html

Comment: Although it might work, downgrading is an inelegant solve that doesn't fix the problem permanently, unfortunately.  The React engineers have included an error to help with future compatibility, so it's best to fix the problem following their recommendations.