# React Bootstrap and React.PropTypes validation function

Tags: javascript, npm, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a `Rails 5` application on which I've installed `browserify` and `react-rails`. I'm able to load components and install packages using `npm`. 
The browser console when loading some external packages i.e. `react-bootstrap` components is filled with **'Warning: You are manually calling a React.PropTypes validation function for the....'** for each single available prop on a component.

I have looked everywhere, but I don't understand how to fix these warnings. Similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998249/react-bootstrap-manually-calling-a-react-proptypes-validation-function) but this does not seem to have an answer applicable to my issue.

Here are my files:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "browserify": "^13.1.0",
    "browserify-incremental": "^3.0.1",
    "fetch": "^1.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery-ujs": "^1.2.2",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1",
    "sweetalert-react": "^0.4.4"
  }
}
```

**application.js**

```
//= require_self
//= require react-server
//= require react_ujs


window.$ = window.jQuery = global.$ = require('jquery');
var React = window.React = global.React = require('react');
var ReactDOM= window.ReactDOM = global.ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
require( 'jquery-ujs' );
require( 'jquery-ui' );
require( 'bootstrap' );
require( 'react-bootstrap' );
require( 'fetch' );
require( './components' );
```

**components.js**

```
var app = window.app = global.app = {};

// Component::Manifest
var AdminDashboard = require( 'components/dashboards/admin' );

app.AdminDashboard = AdminDashboard
```

**admin.js.jsx**

```
var ButtonToolbar = require('react-bootstrap').ButtonToolbar;
var Button = require('react-bootstrap').Button;
var Admin = React.createClass({

  handleClick(){
    alert('This was clicked');
  },


  render: function() {

    return (
      <ButtonToolbar bsClass="btn-group">
        <Button active={true} bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.handleClick}>Primary</Button>
      </ButtonToolbar>
  );
  }
});

module.exports = Admin;
```

How do I get rid of this warning if it's related to an external package and its components?

Comment: I have used react-bootstrap but did not get this error. I used react-bootstrap with webpack.

Comment: I tried using webpack but I'm totally unfamiliar with js and npm etc. So I want entirely sure how to integrate with rails. Do you perhaps know of a good tutorial to help guide me @vijayst?

Comment: This article might help. http://vijayt.com/post/minimal-scaffolding-react-webpack/

Comment: Thanks @vijayst. This looks promising. One thing that confused me before, was the entry.js file. What does this do and do I need it in a rails app where I will make use of standard rails view with some react components embedded?

Comment: This is the tutorial I followed with webpack before: http://aergonaut.com/rails-4-gulp-webpack-react/ . I also installed the react-rails gem in order to get the rails view helper.

Comment: Entry.js file has the initial import / require. It is sort of the App component. If you are using React router, it is the router component. It references all other components. Based on the imports, webpack creates a bundle.js.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to figure out how this fits into the rails environment @vijayst

Comment: If you run: `npm ls react`, what's the output?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2257

Answer (score 1):

This might help - https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html. Basically the library you're using `react-bootstrap` might be using `PropTypes` in a way that is unsupported by React.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading react-bootstrap should fix this issue. It looks like they [addressed this back in June](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/pull/2648)

You can change your package.json to `"react-bootstrap": "^0.31.0"` and see if that works